# Max Likelihood Estimator of the quantile

Tags: maximum-likelihood, quantiles

Let $(X_1, \dots, X_n) \sim Exp(\theta)$ and so
$$f(x; \theta) = \theta e^{-\theta x}$$
where $x>0$ and $\theta > 0$.

I need to find the quantile $q_p$ as a function of $\theta$, the max-likelihood estimator $\hat{q_p}$ of $q_p$ and the exact distribution of $\hat{q_p}$.

I find the quantile
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x \theta e^{-\theta x} dx= 1-e^{-\theta x}
$$

$$
p= 1-e^{-\theta q_p} \Leftrightarrow q_p = -\cfrac{1}{\theta} \log(1-p)
$$

Now, I understand I should calculate $L(q_p)$ in order to find the MLE $\hat{q_p}$, but I can't figure out which function I should take
$$
L(q_p) = \prod_{i=1}^n [?]
$$

I would take $1-e^{-\theta q_p}$ but I have the feeling this is wrong.

Can you help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the MLE invariance principle, the estimator of the paramater $g(\theta)$ is just $g(\hat{\theta})$.

In your case, $g(\theta) = -\frac{1}{\theta}\log(1 - p)$.

So you only have to find the estimator of $\theta$, and then apply $g$ on it, and you will have $\hat{q_p} = g(\hat{\theta})$.